# How do receive a click event for a table?

Tags: material-ui, next.js

in looking at the following documentation (which I believe to be official):

- https://material-ui.com/api/table/
- https://material-ui.com/api/table-row/
- https://material-ui.com/api/table-cell/

nowhere does it suggest that a user can click on the table nor, if it does, how to pick up the event.  I've seen posts everywhere about how 'onClick' doesn't work in various situations and various hacks and workarounds but if it's not in the official documentation, is the position of Material UI that tables cannot be clicked on?

and if it's possible, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope i got you right. But it is possible to use `onClick` on material-ui's table components.

I took the SimpleTable example from material-ui documentation and added `onClick` property to  component.

https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-field-lm7p9?file=/src/SimpleTable.js

```
<Table className={classes.table} onClick={() => alert("Table Click")}>
```

(Works on Cells and Rows as well)

**Edit:**

So, as for your question in the comments:
Material-UI Table component is, at the end of the day, a React component.

(You can take a look at the [source](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/packages/material-ui/src/Table) to explore this and other things)

Every React component has the known HTML/JS events like onClick etc... these events get the function that triggers once the event happens as an argument (it could be alert() like I made In the example.

Comment: but the docs say nothing of onClick.  where do you learn what arguments are passed to this function?

Comment: Hey :) Material-UI Table component is, at the end of the day, a React component. Every React component has the known HTML/JS events like onClick etc... these events get the function that triggers once the event happens as  an argument (it could be alert() like I made In the example. I'll edit my post with this comment information.

Comment: ah.  that's fair.  I'm new to React as well so I didn't know that